# Slidetoggle not working on group of rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am struggling with Jquery Slidetoggle , it is not working on tr and td tags, this is small eample I tried in Jsfiddle, in fact my original code has dynamically generated tr and td tags in a loop and I need to exapand and collapse the tr sections
I even tried in JSfiddle, please help me to find out if my javascript code to drilldown to class "section" is wrong.
https://jsfiddle.net/jsfiddleuser0601/dxgwreyw/1/

```js
$('.show').click( function() {


   alert ("show clicked");
     var content=   $(this).closest('tbody').next('.section');
  //  var content = $(this).closest('tbody').find('.section');
   var title = content.is(':visible') ? "Show" : "Hide";
    content.slideToggle('slow');
    alert("slide toggle operated");
 
     $(this).text(title);
});
```

```html
<table >
     
         <tbody>
             <tr>
                 <td class="show">Show

                 </td>
             </tr>
         </tbody>
         <tbody>
             <tr>
                 <td class="section">
                     section 1
                 </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td class="section">
                     section 1
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </tbody>
     </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achive right now. I feel the HTML syntax is not really full so there might be problems helping you out with the jQuery.

First of all, you haven't included jQuery library in your fiddle thats why nothing is working there.

```
$('.show').click(function() {
  alert("click clicked");

  $('.section').parent().each(function(){
    $(this).slideToggle();
  });

});
```

Please see https://jsfiddle.net/dxgwreyw/4/ fiddle for more understanding how it could possibly work.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. It works great. Just wondering whats wrong with my code , is it the way I navigate to the element using jquery? Also looking to change the ttile to "hide" once slide toggle is done.